# Testing Deployed Smart Contract on Truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm having trouble testing a contract using truffle.   I have the latest version of truffle installed as well a TestRPC.

It's to my understanding that the latest version of truffle comes with a client for testing SmartContracts so TestRPC isn't needed any more.

I have a simple contract my Migrations looks like so:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
var OrdersFacilitator = artifacts.require("./OrdersFacilitator.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(OrdersFacilitator);
};
```

When I run truffle develop I see that 10 test accounts are created.

> Accounts:
>
> (0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
>
> (1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
>   //...

My Truffle js is configured like so:

```
networks: {
  development: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9545,
    network_id: "*"
  }
}
```

When I run the name of my contracts I can see its deployed with the information:

```
//...
class_defaults:
{ from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57',
 gas: 6721975,
 gasPrice: 100000000000 },
currentProvider:
 HttpProvider {
   host: 'http://127.0.0.1:9545/',
   timeout: 0,
   user: undefined,
   password: undefined,
   headers: undefined,
   send: [Function],
   sendAsync: [Function],
   _alreadyWrapped: true },
network_id: '4447' }
```

the Network Id and the port seem to match the configuration fine, and I can see the information when I type the contract name, However when I try to gain access to it though

```
var facilitator;
OrdersFacilitator.deployed().then(x => facilitator = x);
```

I Get an Error:

> OrdersFacilitator has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

I've tried deleting the build folder and migrating all with the --reset flag but that doesn't seem to work. How can I Tested my deployed contract

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in `truffle develop`. Try Ganache — https://truffleframework.com/ganache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue I've explicitly set the network options and network id.

```
//Start Test RPC with an Explicit Network
testrpc --network-id 1337
```

Then I've created an explicit network for TestRPC:

```
networks: {
  testrpc:{
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8545,
    network_id: "1337"
  }
}
```

Now when I Migrate Explicitly to my new network:

```
truffle migrate --network testrpc --reset
truffle console --network testrpc
```

This seems to map properly to the correct network

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issues withe Truffle projects attempting the same thing. The solution may be to reset the project to a non-cached state.

You can try running truffle compile (and/or truffle migrate) with the --reset flag. This will remove the `build` dir and recompile everything.